# How to include the right reference in C# using the "Browser" tab

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am working on VS2010 C# and I want to add a .dll reference compiled under VS2008; this .dll exists in 2 versions: Debug and Release.

The .dll is not under .NET, COM or projects tabs, so I only have the "browser" tab to add the .dll to the reference.

My question is: How can I indicate to VS to take the release .dll version when I compile in the release mode and to take the debug .dll version when I compile in the debug mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably need to manually edit the underlying .csproj file.  Approximately thusly

```
<Reference Condition=" '$Configuration'=='Debug' " 
           Include="path\to\Debug\Foo.dll" />
<Reference Condition=" '$Configuration'=='Release' " 
           Include="path\to\Release\Foo.dll" />
```

(May be easy to add a reference to debug version via browse, then right click project in solution explorer, click 'Unload project', then right click again, 'Edit your.csproj', make the edit suggested above to the Foo.dll that you just added, then right click, 'Reload project'.)

EDIT

To prevent seeing two copies inside VS, maybe something like

```
<Reference debugstuff as before>
    <Visible Condition=debugcond>true</Visible>
    <Visible Condition=releasecond>false</Visible>
</Reference>
and same for release
```

That is, conditionally set `Visible` metadata under the reference node to true/false based on the condition.  I haven't tried to to know if it works.

Comment: Thanks Brian, it is working now. Please, let me ask a one more question related to your answer. When I see the reference option, two lines referred to both the path\to\Debug\Foo.dll and the path\to\Release\Foo.dll are displayed; how can I avoid this behavior? I mean, if I am in Debug mode only the line related to path\to\Debug\Foo.dll should be displayed and so on. Thanks!!

Comment: I added to my answer something to try.

Comment: Brian, seems it doesn't work, the "Visible Condition" is not been recognized by VS. Anyway, your first solution works for me. My best regards.

Answer (score 12):

A better way to implement Brian's solution is to do it this way:

```
<Reference Include="AjaxControlToolkit">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>path/to/folder/bin/$(Configuration)/AjaxControlToolkit.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This will switch nicely between Release and Debug without it showing up twice in your References view.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to add the project to the solution.  It is then entirely automatic.

Comment: Thanks Hans, my problem here is that the .dll components I want to add in the reference were compiled in VS2008. When I try to add the project into the VS2010 solution, it forces me to upgrade the project. I would not like to have duplicated projects (one in 2008 and another in 2010).

Comment: You've already got some projects that only load in 2008, some in 2010.  I recommend you don't let that linger on for too long.  SCCSs are built to make that *not* a problem.

Comment: Hello Hans, I appreciate your recommendation very much. In this moment I am using a trial version of VS2010 and I am not sure if my company is going to pay for it so, I do not want to touch the VS2008 components. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

we found some ideal way to deal with this situation.
first, publish your library file to three special folders:
$(Configuration)\MyLibrary.dll
Debug\MyLibrary.dll
Release\MyLibrary.dll

then in your application, reference the '$(Configuration)\MyLibrary.dll' one.
done! now you change the solution configuration, the dll will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of @Kevin Yang's answer, I did the following:

1. Build into `path\to\Debug\MyCode.dll` and `path\to\Release\MyCode.dll`.
2. Reference one of them in VS (using the 'Browse' tab).
3. Unload the project that is referencing your DLL.
4. Right-click on the unloaded project and click `Edit MyReferencingProject.csproj...`
5. Find the reference, and in the `HintPath` element, change `Debug`/`Release` to `$(Configuration)` (so it should be `path\to\$(Configuration)\MyCode.dll`).
6. Rinse/repeat (with any other similar DLL's).

When you're done, should look like:

```
<Reference Include="MyCode">
  <HintPath>C:\path\to\$(Configuration)\MyCode.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```